# How should I do Chromakey -video-editing?

Tags: audio, osx

I have chromakey -video and I should add a background and audio to it but I am in very starting point. I tried to find an app for iPhone or iPad not finding any good or professional. My friend suggested Adope Master -collection but I need just chromakey i.e. adding some background to for example screen background. Besides Adope Master that comes with a massive amount things, is there some lightweight tools?

**Profile**

> I have access to OSx, iPad, iPhone and Ubuntu -- but I am ready to use the best tools on the market, platform playing not the key role here.

Comment: Unix -biased thread [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56595/chromakey-video-editing-in-unix). This question is about `should`, not about just one-platform.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need the Master Collections. As you say, it comes with a bunch expensive extras.

You can go for the Adobe Premier Pro which comes with a basic chroma keyer, and/or After effects which give you a little more to tweak with.

However, these doesn't come in Unix/Linux versions, but if an option you can check them here:
http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html

Tip: for a small/short project you can "rent" it for a month or two with a much lower price than purchasing the full version.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion +1, I cannot even understand  the differences between Adobe Master collection and Adobe Premiere Pro. What are the things missing and is it easy to upgrade later?

Answer (score 1):

For both Ubuntu and Mac, you can consider giving Blender a try. Although it is a 3D modelling and animation suite, newer versions have extensive and powerful compositing tools, including a good camera tracker, video editor and chroma keyer.

Blender might seem a little hard to understand but it is not. If you are doing a fresh start with a  new software, it's worth trying. Besides, there are lots of useful and good video tutorials to start with. Another good reason to try blender: it's free. It is open source.

For more information on blender, see http://blender.org

Comment: +1 good suggestion, not so resource-intensive candidate in comparison to AfterEffects requiring at least 4GB Ram and recommended 8 GB.

Comment: Besides, it's cross-platform. I think Linux is a powerful option for production workflow. There has been lots of industry standard tools running on unix based systems. They were proprietary softwares, running on closed source unix variations. I think blender project stands in a point that could reveal Linux's and open source's true potential. Also check the Blender Foundation's latest project [Tears of steel](http://mango.blender.org/). It was completed in Blender, and other Open source tools. They also sell a 4 DVD Set that includes the whole production assets. Good way to learn and support.

Comment: ...but I don't own DVD player or CD player, any other way to get them?

Comment: I don't own the DVDs yet, they started to ship them last week or so. Well, I think most of the stuff are stored as data in DVD-ROMs, probably no need for a standalone DVD player, if you meant that. Just a DVD drive will be enough. The content of the DVDs are licensed under Creative Commons. So I think, _but not sure_, owners are free to share them. Just do a search about it to see if you can find anyone received their shipment and shared it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this right or atleast close to correct you will need to use a professional software to some extent...After effects would be your best bet.  You can download a 30-day limitless Trial on their website.  Then do some videocopilot.net tutorials on how to use keylight to do as you need.